# Glicko-2 implementation in R, where to find?

Tags: r, rating

I am looking for an R implemention of the excellent [Glicko-2 algorithm](http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko2.pdf) of Mark Glickman. Thusfar I found [this](https://github.com/Schw4rz/csgo_glicko2) one. Although this is a very nice piece of code I am particularly looking for a code that is able to deal with large data frames with match scores (meaning that it is capable of ranking all the players in the data frame in one go). A bit like the way the [PlayerRatings package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PlayerRatings/index.html) does the trick with e.g. Elo, Glicko. Unfortenately this package doesn't haven an implementation of the Glicko-2 algorithm.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Software requests are off topic on SO.

Comment: I think you are right. My apologies. I will try to find another place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glicko2 and few other algorithms are available in R package `sport`. Possible for two-player and multi-player matchups. Available on [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sport/index.html) and [github](https://github.com/gogonzo/sport). Vignette included, standarized syntax, supported by C++.

Quick snippet

```
# install.packages("sport")
library(sport) 
glicko2 <- glicko2_run(formula = rank|id ~ rider, data = gpheats)

# computation results
print(glicko2)
summary(glicko2)
tail(glicko2$r)
tail(glicko2$pairs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the meantime PlayerRatings R package implemented it as well. But I'll thankfully accept your answer. Very interesting package

Answer (score 0):

If you had noticed the fine print at the bottom of Mark Glickman's page you would have seen (in tiny text admittedly)

- PlayerRatings, an R package implementation of Glicko, as well as a
  few other rating systems

with the link being: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PlayerRatings/

Comment: Yes I know, that's the link I use in my question as well. As I say in my question: Unfortenately this package doesn't haven an implementation of the Glicko-2 algorithm.

Comment: Sorry about that! I was guilty of inattentive linking I'm afraid. At best I suppose you could find a Python version that operates as you wish and then translate, but this would definitely be a plan B…